# Dynamically change background image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm looking into being able to change the background of a webpage to a dynamically generated image at runtime. I'm using javascript and the canvas element to create the backgrounds, which I'm storing in an array so that the user can toggle between them; the images are jpegs

```
// canvas computations snipped

var img = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
this.modifiedanimationarray[0] = new Image();
this.modifiedanimationarray[0].src = img;
```

However, I have noticed that the javascript to manipulate the background is as follows:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('whatever.jpg')";
```

it wants an image from a url, that is created non-dynamically. Is there any way to force the document.body.style.backgroundImage to accept an image created on-the-fly rather than just loading one off a domain?

Comment: what do you mean by on the fly?

Comment: I mean generated in response to something the user does to the webpage, rather than extract an image from a website. So, the on-the-fly image is created as and when needed.

Comment: Yes it could be done. check my updated answer. See this in action on my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) will give you a data url which can be used in place of a regular url. So instead of doing say

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(someimage.jpg)';
```

just replace the url, in this case `someimage.jpg`, with the url you got from toDataURL

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")+')';
```

Demo

```js
function getBG(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('bgcanvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      cX = canvas.width / 2,
      cY = canvas.height / 2;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(cX, cY, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
  return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
}

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+getBG()+')';
```

```css
canvas {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bgcanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Also note you do not need to load a data url into an image object before using it. Meaning you do not need to do:

```
var img = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
this.modifiedanimationarray[0] = new Image();
this.modifiedanimationarray[0].src = img;
```

You would just do

```
var img = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
this.modifiedanimationarray[0] = img;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.modifiedanimationarray[0]+')';
//or just
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+img+')';
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be just what I want. Shame I can't get the rest of the code to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the result of toDataURL like a real URL.

```
var img = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
```

Comment: So, something like this:

 this.modifiedanimationarray[0] = new Image();

 this.modifiedanimationarray[0].src = img;

 this.modifiedanimationarray[1] = new Image();

 this.modifiedanimationarray[1].src = img; 

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.modifiedanimationarray[0] + ")";

and:

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.modifiedanimationarray[1] + ")";

Comment: One thing that concerns me is the use of the "src" tag, when assigning an array element to "hold" the created image; do I use the same tag when assigning the backgroundimage eg 

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.modifiedanimationarray[0].src + ")";

or not? I am thinking you don't need to (??)

Comment: @EventHorizon, if `this.modifiedanimationarray[0].src` is where you are storing the data url you are getting from toDataURL then yes that is how you would use it. Note though you do not need to use an image object to store it/load it, you just use it.